# Evaluation of complex valued integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $p$ be a non-constant real polynomial on $\mathbb{R}$. I would like to show that
\begin{equation*}
\lim _{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} e^{2 \pi i np(x)} dx = 0
\end{equation*}
Obviously, neither the Dominated Convergence Theorem nor the Triangle Inequality for integral works. I'd be grateful if someone could give me some hints.

Comment: Not sure whether it works, but things I would try are : 1. trying to eat the n with a variable substitution (seems hard in this case though) 2. try to view this integral as an integral along a path, and use cauchy's theorem 3. replace n with a contituous parameter t, and differentiate along $t$

Answer (score 3):

Since $p$ is not constant, there is a subdivision $t_0 = 0 <t_1<\ldots<t_m = 1$ such that $p_i = p|_{[t_i,t_{i+1}]}$ is injective. Then you have :
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 e^{2\pi in p(x)}\text dx &=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}e^{2\pi in p_i(x)}\text dx\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \int_{p(t_i)}^{p(t_{i+1})}e^{2i\pi n y}(p_i^{-1})'(y)\text dy
\end{align}

Since $(p_i^{-1})'$ is integrable, the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) implies :
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{p(t_i)}^{p(t_{i+1})}e^{2i\pi n y}(p_i^{-1})'(y)\text dy = 0 $$

and therefore :
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_0^1 e^{2\pi in p(x)}\text dx = 0$$